# What does listening between the lines mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Listen carefully?

[Between the lines](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Between+the+lines)

> "You have to always be listening, and **listening between the lines**, to your customer,” Perlman says.

Source: [CNBC](https://www.cnbc.com/2020/11/10/zumba-fitness-ceo-on-the-biggest-mistake-business-owners-make.html)

Comment: Do you know the idiom "read between the lines?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link gives the meaning of "read between the lines"

> To infer or understand the real or hidden meaning behind the superficial appearance of something. "Lines" refers to lines of text on a printed page.

"Listen between the lines" is not common, but extends the meaning from text to speech.  It means "understand the hidden meaning when (the customer) speaks".